# Android chat application using asmack library

Tags: android, asmack

How to get the hosted rooms in an Android chat application using the asmack library? I am using the following code but I am getting a nullpointerexception.

```
Collection<HostedRoom> rooms = MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, "@conference."+serviceName);
```

Comment: Collection<HostedRoom> rooms = MultiUserChat.getHostedRooms(connection, "service_name");

Comment: to get service name make XmppConnection instance and then call getServiceName

Comment: Thanks @AnjaliTripathi...can u tell me how to get history for one to one chat ?

Comment: You can get it by adding plugin at server side and make web service to get history from server another option  save data to your local database.